# List and Tuple initialized from string object

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples

How the following two are differ:

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> tuple(s)
('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g')
>>> tuple([s])
('string',)
>>> tuple((s))
('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g')
>>> tuple((s,))
('string',)
>>>
```

String is an iterable object thats why it split into multiple element inside the tuple ?

Comment: in case it's confusing to any readers, semantically `(s)` is exactly the same as `s`.  The comma is what makes the inner argument to your last example `(s,)` a `tuple`, not the enclosing parentheses.  Or perhaps you could alternately say the parentheses are necessary but not sufficient. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples are not determined by parenthesis, they are determined by the comma:

```
>>> (1)
1
>>> (1,)
(1,)
>>> (1),
(1,)
>>> 1
1
>>> 1,
(1,)
```

The intermediate parenthesis are removed until an expression is determined:

```
>>> tuple((((('string')))))
('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g')
>>> tuple((((('string'))),))
('string',)
>>> tuple((((('string'),)),))
(('string',),)
```

You see how Python parses these expressions by using [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast)

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("((((('string')))))")
'string'
>>> ast.literal_eval("((((('string')))),)")
('string',)
```

And shows you why `tuple(('string'))` is the same as `tuple('string')`. The extra parenthesis do not create a tuple and are just discarded by the parser.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `tuple` on a string, or any iterable it will do the same thing that calling `list` on a string would do: Loop through the "least deep" (1st dimension) part of the iterable. Take these examples:

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> tuple(s)
('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g')
>>> tuple([s])
('string',)
>>>
>>> tuple((x for x in [s]))
('string',)
```

In the first example, the 1st dimension in `s` is the string 'string', so tuple takes each value from `s`. In the second example, the 1st dimension is the list s, which contains the variable `s`. In this case, the variable itself is the 1st dimension, so the entire string is tupled. This is proven in the final generator case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `list` expects [its parameter to be](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

> may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object.

So, it creates individual strings for each and every character in the string and returns the list. When you enclose it with `[]` or `(,)`, you are creating a list of strings or tuple of strings. So, each element of that is taken and a new list is prepared.